# Calculating all possible intersections

Tags: r, set, intersection

We have a data frame with one column for a category and one column for discrete values. We want to get all possible intersections (number of common values) for all combinations of categories.

I came up with the following code. However, is there something shorter out there? I am sure there is a better way of doing this, a specialized function that does exactly this. The code below can be shortened, of course, for example with `purrr:map`, but that is not my question.

```
## prepare an example data set
df <- data.frame(category=rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=20),
                 value=sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace=T))

cats <- unique(df$category)
n <- length(cats)

## all combinations of 1...n unique elements from category
combinations <- lapply(1:n, function(i) combn(cats, i, simplify=FALSE))
combinations <- unlist(combinations, recursive=FALSE)
names(combinations) <- sapply(combinations, paste0, collapse="")

## for each combination of categories, get the values which belong
## to this category
intersections <- lapply(combinations, 
          function(co) 
             lapply(co, function(.x) df$value[ df$category == .x ]))
intersections <- lapply(intersections, 
    function(.x) Reduce(intersect, .x))
intersections <- sapply(intersections, length)
```

This brings us to my desired outcome:

```
> intersections
    A     B     C     D     E    AB    AC    AD    AE    BC 
   20    20    20    20    20    10     8     8     9     8 
   BD    BE    CD    CE    DE   ABC   ABD   ABE   ACD   ACE 
    8     9     7     8     8     8     8     9     7     8 
  ADE   BCD   BCE   BDE   CDE  ABCD  ABCE  ABDE  ACDE  BCDE 
    8     7     8     8     7     7     8     8     7     7 
ABCDE 
    7
```

Question: is there a way of achieving the same result with less fuzz?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible approach with `data.table` to cast the data.frame and `model.matrix` to count the higher-order interactions:

1. Cast to wide-format by grouping all matching values between categories in the rows (credits to @chinsoon12 for the `dcast` syntax).
2. Identify all higher-order interactions with `model.matrix` and sum over the columns.

```r
library(data.table)

df_wide <- dcast(setDT(df), value + rowid(category, value) ~ category, fun.aggregate = length, fill = 0)
head(df_wide)
#>    value category A B C D E
#> 1:     a        1 1 1 1 1 1
#> 2:     a        2 1 0 0 1 1
#> 3:     a        3 0 0 0 1 0
#> 4:     b        1 1 1 1 0 1
#> 5:     b        2 1 0 1 0 1
#> 6:     c        1 1 1 1 1 1

colSums(model.matrix(~(A + B + C + D + E)^5, data = df_wide))[-1]
#>         A         B         C         D         E       A:B       A:C 
#>        20        20        20        20        20        13        11 
#>       A:D       A:E       B:C       B:D       B:E       C:D       C:E 
#>        12        12        11        13        13        11        13 
#>       D:E     A:B:C     A:B:D     A:B:E     A:C:D     A:C:E     A:D:E 
#>        10         8         9         9         7         9         7 
#>     B:C:D     B:C:E     B:D:E     C:D:E   A:B:C:D   A:B:C:E   A:B:D:E 
#>         8         9         7         8         5         7         5 
#>   A:C:D:E   B:C:D:E A:B:C:D:E 
#>         5         6         4
```

**Data**

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(category=rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=20),
    value=sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace=T))
```